# servicestack.text public static class JsonReader.GetParseFn?

Tags: servicestack

the JsvReader class is public, so it can be consumed in Servicestack StringMapTypeDeserializer class.

Is there any chance the internal JsonReader class, can also be made public for similar reason?

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/Json/JsonReader.Generic.cs

Comment: Ask features like this on the GitHub project site, include a valid real world use-case of why you need it.